# how to get span in tr with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><span data-mydata="data1">first value data1</span></td>
       <td><span data-mydata="data2">first value data2</span></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td><span data-mydata="data1">second value data1</span></td>
       <td><span data-mydata="data2">second value data2</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

I want to change the span texts at the last tr with jquery, I got all the span in the row with:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:last td span')
```

what I want is the span which attr data-mydata is equal to data2.

how can I do it?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center: link Selecting Elements by Attribute](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/#selecting-elements-by-attribute)

Comment: Do you want to set value of span attr or select the span with attr? Answer is relative to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the element based on the attribute value.

```
 $('#myTable tbody tr:last td span[data-mydata="data2"]')
```

---

Use [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) instead of jQuery [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) for making it more faster.

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:last-child td span[data-mydata="data2"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:last span[data-mydata="data2"]').text('to whatever text you want.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#myTable').find('span[data-mydata="data2"]').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `last` selector to get the last `tr` then use `[attribute=value]`

```js
$("tr:last span[data-mydata='data2']").css({"background": "gold"})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><span data-mydata="data1">first value data1</span></td>
       <td><span data-mydata="data2">first value data2</span></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td><span data-mydata="data1">second value data1</span></td>
       <td><span data-mydata="data2">second value data2</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:last td span').attr('data-mydata','data2')
```